# Getting a particular ID from a web-grid for a modal

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I want a model to open when I click on a button in a web-grid.  I have created a button which targets a modal by its ID.  For each item in the model(a list), I want to create a modal with the id of the item.  Below is my code:

```
<div id="divCurrentRented">
@{
    WebGrid obj = new WebGrid(Model, rowsPerPage: 5);
}

@obj.Table(htmlAttributes: new
{
    id="tableCurrentRented",
    @class = "table"
},
headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
columns: obj.Columns(
    obj.Column("Title", header: "Title"),
    obj.Column("Author", header: "Author"),
    obj.Column("Avaible", header: "Available", canSort:false),
    obj.Column(header: "Rent", format:@<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#@item.BookID">Yes</button>)

            ))
```

As you can see the data target of the button is equal to the id of the item.

my modal code as below:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="@Model.First().BookID" ( role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Return confirmation</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p class="modalBody">Are you sure you want to return this book?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see in the first line, I am fetching the bookID of the first item.  What I need is to fetch the id for each item of the list so that each button click would open its corresponding modal.  Any idea how to do that?

Comment: The most easiest way is this http://jsfiddle.net/9pkbnanz/2/

Comment: This works, but what if I want to add another element in my modal? The book title for example?

Comment: in this example, check first two modal button trigger code for title example and then open those modals to see title pass to modals along with ids http://jsfiddle.net/9pkbnanz/3/

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Put it as answer so that I can accept it!

Comment: sure, give me a moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass information from page to modal while staying to same page, you can do with [bootstrap modal event listener](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events) `show` or `shown` and pass the data attributes value to modal

e.g to pass `id` and `title` to modal as data attributes inside modal trigger button.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="123" data-title="I'm First Modal Title">Open Modal</button>
```

and use `event property relatedTarget` to get the data-attribute value e.g `id` inside `modal event listener`

```
var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
```

and pass it to modal e.g to `<div class="modal-body"></div>`

```
$(".modal-body").html(id);
```

example with `id` and `title` as data attributes passing to modal

```js
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
    var title = $(e.relatedTarget).data('title');
    //pass date-title to modal header
    $(".modal-title").html(title);
    //Pass Id to modal body or any element in modal
    $(".modal-body").html(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="123" data-title="I'm First Modal Title">Open Modal</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="456" data-title="I'm Second Modal Title">Open Modal</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
 <!-- Modal content-->
 <div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"> <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" aria-labellbyid="writeLabel"></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body"></div>
  <div class="modal-footer" id="edit-footer">
   <input type="submit" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9pkbnanz/3/)